# I can't click on Telerik controls in my WinForms application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, telerik

I’m having an issue w/ a WinForms app I built several months ago.  I opened it yesterday for the first time in a few months, and I’m unable to click on any of the controls in the form (in Designer view).  If I double-click any of the controls on the page, it opens up code for the Load event of the form, as if I double-clicked the form itself; it’s as if the form is on top of all other controls maybe?  All of the controls on the form are Telerik controls.  I've been working on this project in VS 2010 since its inception.  I also tried opening it in VS 2012 this morning, but that didn't help.

If I drag a new Telerik control to the form, it vanishes instantly, as if it’s buried under all of the other controls.  If I drag a non-Telerik control to the form (such as a standard textbox), it appears fine, and that control will respond to clicks (ie – the Properties window will populate w/ properties for that control).

After I noticed this issue yesterday, I reluctantly upgraded my Telerik WinForms controls to Q3 this morning, but that hasn’t helped anything.

For now, I was able to bypass the Designer view altogether, and I made changes via the Designer code class.  However, I’ll be in trouble if I ever need to actually add a new Telerik control to this form.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: looks like that's how the **third-party UI lib providers** protect their products from being used illegally (such as some cracked lib?) I'm not sure if that's the case but it's a possibility.

Comment: I have a valid Telerik license.  Like I said, I even upgraded this morning to the Q3 release, just in case there was an issue w/ outdated DLLs .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a missing design time assembly. Please have a look at the following articles for explanation and suggestions how to handle this: [link](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/general/radcontrols-for-winforms-are-not-loaded-at-design-time.aspx) [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/installation-deployment-and-distribution-vsx-design-time-assembly-handling.html)

Comment: Thanks, that got me closer.  I'm now able to select individual Telerik controls on the form.  However, now when I try to open the Property Builder on a RadGridView object, I get this error - "Error invoking 'Open Property Builder'.  Details: The value "Telerik.WinControls.Data.SortDescriptor" is not of type "Telerik.WinControls.Data.SortDescriptor" and cannot be used in this generic collection.  Parameter name: value